# Submenu Dropdown behind Nivo Slider in IE

Tags: css, wordpress

Website utilizing wordpress theme called Boldy. Main menu utilizes submenu and home page utilizes the Nivo Slider.  "Services" submenu is buried beneath the Slider only in IE9.

I've tried changing the z-index values, but no luck.  Style sheet located at: http://debraraftery.com/wp-content/themes/boldy/style.css

Comment: By default, the sub menu will not hide beneath the slider in IE. Because I'm also using the same theme for my website. [Check this](http://lanscreative.in/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the '**?**', line **947**, in the *style.css* file.

It should work then.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem with Beauty template, solved it with z-index:2000 in #header